# Marklogic DataHub Error :The specified flow is missing. (MISSING_FLOW

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am new in the Marklogic DataHub i have setup the DHF on Marklogic version 9.0-5.1  DHF version is v3.0.0 as DHF tutorial datahub quickstart given the step i am doing but when i click Run Import job created and failed with error "The specified flow  is missing. (MISSING_FLOW):"  can anyone suggest what i am missing.

Error:

13:29:28.529 [main] INFO  c.m.contentpump.LocalJobRunner - Content type: XML
13:29:28.963 [main] INFO  c.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump - Job name: local_1095900964_1
13:29:29.001 [main] INFO  c.m.c.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 4
13:29:30.400 [pool-1-thread-4] WARN  c.m.contentpump.TransformWriter - Failed document /board_games_apparel.csv-0-1
13:29:30.400 [pool-1-thread-4] WARN  c.m.contentpump.TransformWriter - The specified flow  is missing. (MISSING_FLOW):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable error you are doing is while selecting the Input Folder path which you downloaded as "store-data.zip".

Try deleting this project and create a new project. Be careful while giving the input path.

If you are a beginner, then best way is to create the folder structure similar to the one which they have created in tutorial i.e; data-hub/input folder and then place your store-data folder inside it.

Comment: Thanks Shalni, It was problem with the input path .

Comment: Glad it helped :)